# Create excel file with OpenXml connected with database

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, database, openxml

I want to create an excel file with openXML library. Document should be connected with database, and contain in single/multiple sheets different data received by different queries. Example result:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable1 -- data from first table
SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable2 -- data from second table
```

Document: 
[image]

As far I have some working part of code:

```
Sheets sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            ConnectionsPart connPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<ConnectionsPart>();
            connPart.Connections = new Connections();

            var connection = new Connection()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Connection",
                Type = 5, //ODBC
                SaveData = true,
                RefreshOnLoad = true,
                RefreshedVersion = 5,
                MinRefreshableVersion = 1,
                Background = true,
                DatabaseProperties = new DatabaseProperties
                {
                    Connection =
                        "my-connection-string",
                    Command = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable1",
                },
            };

            connPart.Connections.Append(connection);

            QueryTablePart qt = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<QueryTablePart>();

            qt.QueryTable = new QueryTable()
            {
                Name = "Connection",
                ConnectionId = connection.Id,
                AutoFormatId = 16,
                ApplyNumberFormats = true,
                ApplyBorderFormats = true,
                ApplyFontFormats = true,
                ApplyPatternFormats = true,
                ApplyAlignmentFormats = false,
                ApplyWidthHeightFormats = false,
                AdjustColumnWidth = true,
                Headers = false,
                RefreshOnLoad = true
            };

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "mySheet"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            sheets.Append(qt.QueryTable);

            DefinedNames definedNames = new DefinedNames();
            // Create a new range (name matching the QueryTable name) 
            DefinedName definedName = new DefinedName() { Name = "Connection", Text = "mysheet!$B$2:$B$2",  };

            definedNames.Append(definedName);
            workbookpart.Workbook.Append(definedNames);


            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
```

For single connection with single command works ok. Problem is that I don't know how to change code, to work on multiple commands (queries). When I tried to add second connection and second QueryTablePart, document was created, but content was broken, with error saying that there should be single root element for QueryTablePart. Can someone help me? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Ok, as alwayes, I found solution by myself. To all work correctly, you have to pass QueryTablePart Id in constructor. Working code part:

```
var connection = new Connection()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Connection",
                Type = 5, //ODBC
                SaveData = true,
                RefreshOnLoad = true,
                RefreshedVersion = 5,
                MinRefreshableVersion = 1,
                Background = true,
                DatabaseProperties = new DatabaseProperties
                {
                    Connection =
                        "connection-string",
                    Command = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable1",
                },
            };

            var connection1 = new Connection()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Connection1",
                Type = 5, //ODBC
                SaveData = true,
                RefreshOnLoad = true,
                RefreshedVersion = 5,
                MinRefreshableVersion = 1,
                Background = true,
                DatabaseProperties = new DatabaseProperties
                {
                    Connection =
                        "connection-string",
                    Command = "SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable2",
                },
            };
            connPart.Connections.Append(connection);
            connPart.Connections.Append(connection1);

            QueryTablePart qt = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<QueryTablePart>("part1");//IMPORTANT
            QueryTablePart qt2 = worksheetPart.AddNewPart<QueryTablePart>("part2");//IMPORTANT

            qt.QueryTable = new QueryTable()
            {
                Name = "Connection",
                ConnectionId = connection.Id,
                AutoFormatId = 16,
                ApplyNumberFormats = true,
                ApplyBorderFormats = true,
                ApplyFontFormats = true,
                ApplyPatternFormats = true,
                ApplyAlignmentFormats = false,
                ApplyWidthHeightFormats = false,
                AdjustColumnWidth = true,
                Headers = false,
                RefreshOnLoad = true
            };
            qt2.QueryTable = new QueryTable()
            {
                Name = "Connection1",
                ConnectionId = connection1.Id,
                AutoFormatId = 16,
                ApplyNumberFormats = true,
                ApplyBorderFormats = true,
                ApplyFontFormats = true,
                ApplyPatternFormats = true,
                ApplyAlignmentFormats = false,
                ApplyWidthHeightFormats = false,
                AdjustColumnWidth = true,
                Headers = false,
                RefreshOnLoad = true
            };

            // Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
                SheetId = 1,
                Name = "mySheet"
            };
            sheets.Append(sheet);
            sheets.Append(qt.QueryTable);
            sheets.Append(qt2.QueryTable);

            DefinedNames definedNames = new DefinedNames();
            // Create a new range (name matching the QueryTable name) 
            DefinedName definedName = new DefinedName() { Name = "Connection", Text = "mysheet!$B$2:$B$2",  };
            DefinedName definedName1 = new DefinedName() { Name = "Connection1", Text = "mysheet!$C$2:$C$2", };

            definedNames.Append(definedName);
            definedNames.Append(definedName1);
            workbookpart.Workbook.Append(definedNames);


            workbookpart.Workbook.Save();
```